# Value displayed twice in output (C programming)

Tags: c, file

I wrote a program to print odd and even numbers in separate files. My program is

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *f1,*f2,*f3;
    int n,i,num;

    f1 = fopen("number.txt","w");
    printf("Enter the number:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
         fprintf(f1,"%d ",i);
    fprintf(f1,"\n");
    fclose(f1);

    f1 = fopen("number.txt","r");
    f2 = fopen("even.txt","w");
    f3 = fopen("odd.txt","w");

    fprintf(f2,"Even numbers:\n");
    fprintf(f3,"Odd numbers:\n");

    while(!feof(f1)){
         fscanf(f1,"%d",&num);
         if(num%2 == 0)
              fprintf(f2,"%d ",num);
         else
              fprintf(f3,"%d ",num);
    }

    fclose(f1);
    fclose(f2);
    fclose(f3);
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is

```
Enter the number:10
$ cat number.txt
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 

$ cat even.txt
Even numbers:
2 4 6 8 10 10 

$ cat odd.txt
Odd numbers:
1 3 5 7 9
```

Why am I getting two 10s in the even output?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["while( !feof( file ) )" is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagnosis by [fbrereto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/153535/fbrereto) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27056032/15168) is accurate.  The prescribed fix is less satisfactory, though.

The fixed code should be:

```
while (fscanf(f1, "%d", &num) == 1)
{
    if (num % 2 == 0)
        fprintf(f2, "%d ", num);
    else
        fprintf(f3, "%d ", num);
}
putc('\n', f2);
putc('\n', f3);
```

Answer (score 3):

`feof` is `true` when you have read *at* or *past* the end of the file.

The `scanf` operation that reads `10` (the last number) will not set the `eof` bit because you have not tried to read at or past the end of the file yet. The loop runs again, *then* the `eof` bit is set during `scanf`, but you output whatever was in `num` before (the last number), hence the double output.

One possible fix would be to make the while loop `while (true)`, and make the `feof` check immediately after `fscanf`, `break`ing if so.

Answer (score 0):

The following is working as you expected, and it's only one line more, albeit I'm not sure it's the best and most clean way:

```
//
//  main.c
//  evenOdd
//

#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

    FILE *f1,*f2,*f3;
    int n,i,num;

    f1 = fopen("number.txt","w");
    printf("Enter the number:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        fprintf(f1,"%d ",i);
    fprintf(f1,"\n");
    fclose(f1);

    f1 = fopen("number.txt","r");
    f2 = fopen("even.txt","w");
    f3 = fopen("odd.txt","w");

    fprintf(f2,"Even numbers:\n");
    fprintf(f3,"Odd numbers:\n");

    for (i=1; !feof(f1); ++i) {
            fscanf(f1, "%d", &num);
        if (feof(f1) != 0) {return 0;} else // check if EOF
            if (num%2 == 0) {
                fprintf(f2, "%d ", num);
            } else fprintf(f3, "%d ", num);
        }


    fclose(f1);
    fclose(f2);
    fclose(f3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is much better to test the I/O function (`fscanf()` in this case) than to use `feof()`.  You use `feof()` after you've already spotted a problem to distinguish between EOF and an error (`ferror()` tells you it was an error).  But that's the only legitimate use of `feof()`.  Loop controls or double-testing `feof()` are clumsy at best and more usually erroneous.